# SQL Server integrated security precedence in the connection string

Tags: .net, sql-server, .net-core

In .Net, if the SQL Server connection string has `Integrated Security=true;` and there is a `user id=bob;` provided, which one 'wins'?  Will .Net connect with the windows account or the SQL Server account?

Does this happen to be documented anywhere?  I've read through [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx) and I didn't see anything.

```
Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=Northwind;server=(local);User ID=bob;Password=stackoverflow;
```

Comment: I am not sure about docs but its always use integrated security and ignore credentials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is right there, in that article you mention - a bit down (about halfway down in the document):

> Integrated Security
>   -or-
>   Trusted_Connection
>
> If User ID and Password are specified and Integrated Security is set to true, the User ID and Password **will be ignored** and **Integrated Security will be used**.